# Views 3 : Set header/footer/empty text for view via views_embed_view

Tags: views

I update my views from views 2 and I do the same on embedded code. But actually I can't set footer content as it changes in views 3.

My views 2 code :

```
$emptyTextVue = $view->display_handler->get_option('empty');
$emptyText = $view->display_handler->set_option('empty','<div class="ma-classe">Pas images.</div>');
```

I think I do use the export code like :

```
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['content'] = 'Pas d\'images à afficher.';
```

but how ?

EDIT : extract result for var_dump() : `["handler_type"]=> string(5) "empty" ["options"]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(4) "area" ["table"]=> string(5) "views" ["field"]=> string(4) "area" ["relationship"]=> string(4) "none" ["group_type"]=> string(5) "group" ["ui_name"]=> string(0) "" ["label"]=> string(13) "Zone de texte" ["empty"]=> int(0) ["content"]=> string(25) "Pas d'images à afficher." ["format"]=> string(1) "2" ["tokenize"]=> int(0) } ["definition"]=> array(4) { ["handler"]=> string(23) "views_handler_area_text" ["group"]=> string(6) "Global" ["title"]=> string(13) "Zone de texte" ["help"]=> string(33) "Provide markup text for the area." } ["is_handler"]=> bool(true) ["localization_keys"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(7) "default" [1]=> string(5) "empty" [2]=> string(5) "views" [3]=> string(4) "area" } ["table"]=>`

Comment: Why views_embed_view?

Comment: because i put the code into a custom node.tpl; but for now empty text from views isn't display too..i think code has changed in V3...but i can't find a list of that snippets.actually the view display "Array" as empty text..

Comment: See below for snippet...

Comment: Do you have an empty text field added to your view via the UI and you just want to set the text, or there is no empty text handler on the view and you want to add it in the code?

Comment: it's the second option, no handler and i want ot add it via code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First up, don't use views_embed_view(). It is a very simple function that doesn't allow for customisation.

Do something like this:

```
// Load the view.
$view = views_get_view('VIEW_NAME');
// Set the options for the header text.
// To get an idea of what options are available, set up a view with header text
// and then use the devel module to print out the view definition.
// For example, add a header text area field and print it with
// dpm($view->header['area']); after you have loaded it with views_get_view().
$header_options = array(
  'label' => t('Header text'), // Administrative label. Not really needed here.
  'content' => 'This is the header text content.', // Content of header text.
  'format' => 'filtered_html', // Format of header text.
  'empty' => 1, // Show even when there are no results. Set to zero otherwise.
);
// This adds a header handler for a text area. The table is views because it is not
// a database field. The field is area because it is a text area.
// The header_options are the settings.
$view->add_item('DISPLAY_NAME', 'header', 'views', 'area', $header_options);
// This is the preferred way to get the rendered view.
$output = $view->preview('DISPLAY_NAME');
// If you want you can check for results with this.
if (!empty($view->result)) {
  // Do something if there are rows.
}
```

You can do the same for footer handlers:

```
$view->add_item('DISPLAY_NAME', 'footer', 'views', 'area', $footer_options);
```

and empty text:

```
$view->add_item('DISPLAY_NAME', 'empty', 'views', 'area', $empty_options);
```

You can also change the field type if you don't want to use Global: Text area.

For more information see [$view->add_item()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/function/views_db_object%3a%3aadd_item/7)

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like the following. I'm using some Views hook functions to interact with a View object -- you probably want to [review a blog post tutorial on some ways to embed views](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/2744/drupal-7-views-3-x-how-to-programmatically-render-a-view-display-passing-exposed-filter-inputs-via-code-using-view):

1. get a view
2. assign a display
3. add/remove filters
4. embed the view

After (2) above you have a `$view` object you can modify essentially as I do below. [Another good resource (I think) on embedding views can be seen in the Embed Views contrib module](http://drupal.org/project/embed_views) documentation page.

I just happen to have this code around, the first function alters view Filters. The second function alters the default empty text.

Remember to edit the particular `$view[$display_id]` and its `$handlers` to see your changes at run-time.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_pre_view().
 *
 * Change the set filter to be the current Quarter/Year set in the CCS admin area.
 */
function courses_db_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  // This is /DEPT/courses
  #dpm($view);
  if ($view->name == 'departmental_courses') {
    $filter =& $view->filter;

    $fall_tid = 11;
    $year_2012_tid = 26;
    // We created these _tid variables so that we didn't have to look up the TID
    // on every page view by students.
    $q = variable_get('ccs_current_quarter_tid', $fall_tid);
    $y = variable_get('ccs_current_year_tid', $year_2012_tid);

  $view->display[$display_id]->handler->options['filters']['field_coursedb_quarter_tid']['value'] = $q;
  $view->display[$display_id]->handler->options['filters']['field_coursedb_year_tid']['value'] = $y;
  }
  if ($view->name == 'courses_for_instructor') {
    #dpm($view->display['block']->handler, 'handler');
    $quarter = variable_get('ccs_current_quarter', 'Fall');
    $year = variable_get('ccs_current_year', '2012');

    $view->display['block']->handler->options['title'] = t('@quarter @year Instructor of:', array('@quarter' => $quarter, '@year' => $year));
    $view->args[0] = $year;
    $view->args[1] = $quarter;
    #dpm($view->display['block']->handler, 'handler');
  }

}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_post_execute().
 *
 * For a view listing of migrated course data, show original legacy
 * data in the view header to allow auditing/verification of the
 * migrated data.
 */
function courses_db_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'migration_audits') {  # Courses

    $drupal_nids = array();
    if (count($view->result)) {
      foreach ($view->result as $i => $node) {
        $drupal_nids []= $node->nid;
      }
    }

    $ccs_sql = <<<EOFSQL
SELECT mccd.*
FROM ccs_dump.mos_ccs_courses_db mccd
LEFT JOIN ccs_dump.migrate_map_csscourse mmc ON mmc.sourceid1 = mccd.id
WHERE mmc.destid1 IN (:drupal_nids)
EOFSQL;
    $result = db_query($ccs_sql, array(':drupal_nids' => $drupal_nids));
    $output = '';
    foreach ($result as $course) {
      #dpm($course);
      $title = html_entity_decode($course->course_title, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
      $instructors = html_entity_decode($course->instructor, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
      $output .= "<div class=\"entry\">$course->quarter $course->year - $title Instructors:&nbsp;$instructors</div>";
    }


    $ccs_values = "<style type=\"text/css\">div.legacy_values { background-color: pink;} div.legacy_values div.entry { padding-bottom: 5px; }</style><div class=\"legacy_values\">$output</div>";
    $view->display['page']->handler->handlers['header']['area_1']->options['content'] = $ccs_values;
    $view->display['page']->handler->handlers['header']['area_1']->options['empty'] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: i go ahead with this but my footer doesn't display ,my variable is the right one..`$footer_text = '<a href="/node/8" >Voir les archives</a>';
//Pour Views 3 
$emptyTextVue_v3 = $view->handler->handlers['header']['area_1']->options['empty'] = TRUE;
$FooterV3 = $view->display[$viewdisplay_ag5]->display_options['footer'] = "$footer_text";`i think the issue is in the output of the view actually done with : `$output = '<div id="other-sortie"><h3 class="CLASS_NAME">'.$view->get_title().'</h3>' .$view->preview($viewdisplay_ag5,$args_ag5).'</div>';`

Comment: no need to change code for empty text..only footer/header seem to need change whith views 3

Comment: still there...your example is to complicated for me,i don't use a module, only an php includes files in a custom tpl file to embed my view..actually

Comment: still there...your example is to complicated for me,i don't use a module, only an php includes files in a custom tpl file to embed my view..actually i would to display header content and footer content from the views UI..

Comment: It doesnt matter if you use a module. You can call a view from any tpl file using PHP code. You want to set something like:
`$view->display['page']->handler->handlers['header']['area_1']->options['content'] = "your custom message";`
if you want a footer you just set `handlers[footer]` i believe.

Comment: how can i know with area i need to use in my php ? i believe it could be the area_1 for each header, footer and empty text ? or the area_1, area_2 etc...for global areas ?

Comment: `$view->display['page']->handler->handlers['header']` will have an array of areas. You as the developer need to know with view XXX the right area_N to use. Same thing for footers. The `$view` is an object check for fields you want, alter them, or _add_ them if you need to.