# Can I use a universal no-results display for Views?

Tags: views

In Drupal 7, is there a way to set a default, universal No results message for Views? Which of these following options should work?

[image]

Should I use a `Rendered Entity`? If so can I create a node (say, called 'no-results')? Is the Entity Id field, the URL of the entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy [views-view.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view.tpl.php/7) template to your theme folder, then modify relevant part.

```
<?php if ($rows): ?>
  <div class="view-content">
    <?php print $rows; ?>
  </div>
<?php elseif ($empty): ?>
  <div class="view-empty">
    <?php print $empty; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To:

```
<?php if ($rows): ?>
  <div class="view-content">
    <?php print $rows; ?>
  </div>
<?php else: ?>
  <!-- HTML for no results here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can keep the `<?php elseif ($empty): ?>` part if you still want to be able to override your custom output.

Cheers,

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best (and most maintainable)

Comment: And sometimes you have to weigh the effort between most simple and best. The best might be to try to override/replace the `$empty` var. [This question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49160/views-3-set-header-footer-empty-text-for-view-via-views-embed-view) might be of some help.